# Type: Error Message: Call to undefined method Main_model

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

I am not able to figure it out the error can any one help me ..

Below is the code.

main_model.php

```
<?php
class Main_model extends CI_Model {

  // function fetch_data($selecteddate){
  //   //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `userLocationLogcat` WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM userLocationLogcat GROUP BY email )");
  //   return 0;
  // }

  public function getUsers(){
    return 0;
  }

}
?>
```

welcome.php(controller)

```
public function one(){
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $data = $this->main_model->getUsers();
        echo $data;
    }
```

please help.

Comment: Are your files in UCFirst? As in Main_model.php and Welcome.php instead of main_model.php and welcome.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your model file name. first letter always capital , 
for example main_model.php to Main_model.php

Answer (score 0):

Check that the filenames are capitalized on the first (and only the first) character, such as `Main_model.php` as it is a convention CI expects and enforces

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your model filename is **Main_model.php**
- If you want to call Main_model from controller you can try use **`__construct()`**

  `public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('main_model');
  }`

  `public function one() {
      $data = $this->main_model->getUsers();
      echo $data;
  }`